# Simple 2.6.7 doesn't handle enums in the same way as Simple 2.6 does?

Tags: java, enums, xml-serialization, simple-framework

Consider the following enum annotated with simple-xml annotations:

```
@Root(name="days")
public enum DaysOfWeek {

    SUNDAY("blue", 30),
    MONDAY("green", 60),
    TUESDAY("yellow", 50),
    WEDNESDAY("red", 45),
    THURSDAY("black", 45),
    FRIDAY("white", 65),
    SATURDAY("brown", 40);

    @Attribute(name="color")
    private String color;

    @Element(name="mins")
    private int minutes;


    DaysOfWeek(String color, int minutes){
        this.color = color;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    DaysOfWeek(){
        /*
         * Default constructor
         */
    }

    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes){
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return this.color;

    }

    public int getMinutes(){
        return this.minutes;
    }
}
```

And, the code that uses simple framework to serialize it into XML:

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.write(DaysOfWeek.TUESDAY, writer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

With simple-2.6, I see this output - which is what I expect:

```
<days color="yellow">
   <mins>50</mins>
</days>
```

However, the **same code**, when serialized with simple-2.6.7, gives this:

```
<daysOfWeek>TUESDAY</daysOfWeek>
```

Basically, in simple-2.6.7, the individual members of an enum (and the simple-xml annotations on them) are ignored and always the name of the enum constant is used for serialization.

Is this intended? How do I get the latest version of simple-xml to serialize an enum while taking the individual members of the enum into consideration?

Comment: I have just tried the latest version of Simple XML (2.7.0).  The issue seems to remain.

Comment: The issue remains in 2.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one entry containing *enum* in the [changelog](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download.php) for (2.6.x) releases:

> **Simple 2.6.3:**
>    - Bug fix made to ensure abstract enums can be serialized properly

But why do you want `color` and `minutes` to get serialized? If you serialize and deserialize `DaysOfWeek`, the enums will get their values according your definition (constructor).

---

Anyway you can use a `Converter` for customizing your XML:

### Annotations of `DaysOfWeek`:

```
@Root(name = "days")
@Convert(DaysOfWeekConverter.class)
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** you don't need `@Element` or `@Attribute` annotations anymore, the "content" of the xml for this class is specified by the `Converter` now.

### *(Possible)* Implementation of `Converter`-Interface:

```
public class DaysOfWeekConverter implements Converter<DaysOfWeek>
{
    @Override
    public DaysOfWeek read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        DaysOfWeek rtn = getDayByColor(node.getAttribute("color").getValue());
        rtn.setMinutes(Integer.valueOf(node.getNext("mins").getValue()));

        return rtn;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, DaysOfWeek value) throws Exception
    {
        node.setName("days");
        node.setAttribute("color", value.getColor());
        node.getChild("mins").setValue("" + value.getMinutes());
    }


    private DaysOfWeek getDayByColor(String color)
    {
        for( DaysOfWeek value : DaysOfWeek.values() )
        {
            if( value.getColor().equals(color) )
                return value;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Day available for color \'" + color + "\'");
    }
}
```

### *(Exmample)* Using the Converter:

```
/*
 * Setting 'AnnotationStrategy' is requried here - else the Converter will get ignored.
 */
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ser.write(DaysOfWeek.TUESDAY, sw);

// ...

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.toString());
DaysOfWeek day = ser.read(DaysOfWeek.class, sr);

// ...
```

### Serialized XML *(from Example)*:

```
<days color="yellow">
   <mins>50</mins>
</days>
```

**Documentation:**

- [Converter (JavaDoc)](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/Converter.html)
- [AnnotationStrategy (JavaDoc)](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/AnnotationStrategy.html)

Comment: The problem with allowing values according to constructor is that I cannot control what's in an attribute versus element. The developer of simple framework has [stated that](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=91F89A63AE64CF4692B740C52E446768EADD72%40DC1INTADCW8201.yieldbroker.com&forum_name=simple-support) he will look into this and probably fix it in the next release. +1 to you for providing a work-around.